# Flex 3 - Resize effect "issue"?

Tags: apache-flex, events, resize, effect

I'm having a little issue with the resize event and resize effect of a VBox.

I have something like this:

```
<mx:VBox id="container"
     backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"
     backgroundAlpha=".9"
     paddingTop="15"
     paddingLeft="15"
     paddingBottom="15"
     verticalGap="5"
     width="210"
     maxHeight="340"
     resizeEffect="{resize}"
     verticalScrollPolicy="off"
     borderStyle="solid">
.
.
.
</mx:VBox>
<mx:Resize id="resize"/>
```

Inside the vbox, I have some items that collapse/expand depending on the user interaction. The problem is that when the user expands an item, the vbox resizes to its maximum height and then shrinks to fit the actual height.

Does anyone know how prevent it from resizing to its maximum height and shrinking back to its actual height??

Thanks for any help you can provide =)

Regards.
BS_C3

Comment: My guess is to Override updateDisplayList of the VBox and deal with the resizing there to make sure the VBox doesn't expand larger than you need it.  It is tough to guess based on the code segment you provided, though.  Give me a full runnable sample demoing the problem and I may be able to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

From you question, it seems to have a problem with the maxHeight property being set. Maybe try removing `maxHeight="340"` and replace with

```
resize="{if(container.height > 340) container.height = 340}"
```

Comment: Great! I'm gonna try that! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, place the VBox inside another container. Set the VBox height to 100%, and do the resizing on the outter container. Ive solved loads of resizing issues using this type of layout.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I'll get back to you once I try it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try setting back to NaN to let Flex figure it out.

```
heightTo="{NaN}"
```